# Persistent Duplicate Filtering in Scrapy

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, web-scraping

I have just started using scrapy and I would like a way to persist the URLs that have previously been crawled so I can run subsequent scrapes and only take in new data from unknown URLs. I am seeing a couple of different ways to filter for duplicates and a couple of ways to persist data. I would like to know what the recommended way for doing these activities is in scrapy version 0.24. Here are the options as I see them:

**For duplicate filtering**

There is the `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` in the `settings.py` file which is still referenced in the documentation. I have also seen documentation refer to putting a duplicate filter in the `ItemPipeline` as seen here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html?highlight=duplicates#duplicates-filter

Are people using `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` or putting a dupefilter in an Item Pipeline?

**For persistent duplicate tracking**

I have tried to use `scrapy-redis` to persist the URLs that have previously been scraped so they can then be used by a duplicate filter, but it seems that any `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` that I am using is ignored. I also see that there is `spider.state` which will store a dictionary if you use the `JOBDIR` option at runtime, but this doesn't seem to be very optimal to use for duplicate filtering.

Can anyone point me to a code sample that can be used to persist data between batches and do duplicate filtering?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a code snippet nor enough rep to comment on your question but here is a suggestion for the persistent url dupe filtering idea.

Keep a database of crawled urls.

Implement a downloader middleware that does the following (pythonish pseudo code):

```
if url isn't present: 
   add url to databse
   return None    # this tells scrapy to keep handling request as normal
else:
   raise IgnoreRequest
```

HTH

edit:
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html

If you are using a crawl spider you can do this for the non-persistent filtering:

```
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(unique=True,
                           deny=[r'.*QuickInfo.*'],
                           allow_domains=allowed_domains,
                           restrict_xpaths=['//*[starts-with(@id, "e")]//a',
                                            '//*[starts-with(@id, "HP_Priority")]//a']),
         follow=True),)
```

unique=True will filter duplicate requests for this spider instance.